# sudo command won't run from script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Linux Mint.

Ok, this is going to be seriously basic but for some reason, I am mis-understanding how this works.

If I type the following commands, everything works fine:

```
cd home/user/folder1/folder1/

sudo openvpn --auth-nocache --config /home/user/folder2/folder2/config-file.ovpn
```

I input the sudo password and all is good.

If I put these commands into a script file, I get nothing but 'command not found'.

I have placed the script file in a folder, added both the script AND the opvn folders to the path.

I created a new script (without the paths) in the same folder as the opvn files, ran it from there and fail.

```
sudo opvn-script.sh 
[sudo] password for <user>: 
sudo: opvn-script.sh: command not found
```

What I don't understand is the script file itself can't be the thing 'not found' because it auto-completes after I type a the first few characters and hit tab.  openvpn can't be the 'not found' because I can run the commands straight up.

The script file IS marked as executable.

`echo $PATH` shows both folders in the path.

What the heck is left??

Comment: Different users have different PATHs.  It would seem that `opvn-script.sh ` is in the PATH for the current user but not for root.  Try: `sudo /path/to/opvn-script.sh`

Comment: Yup, that did it!  So, what is best then? Add the path to su by switching to su, export path?

Comment: There are many solutions.  One might be to create a shell alias that  types out `sudo /path/to/opvn-script.sh` for you.  Another might be just to move `opvn-script.sh` to some convenient place on root's current PATH.

Comment: Thanks again.  The alias seems less secure than simply moving the script somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this error message:

```
sudo: opvn-script.sh: command not found
```

This occurred after you entered the password and indicates that, under the PATH of the new user (root), the script could not be found.

One solution is:

```
sudo /path/to/opvn-script.sh
```

If that works, then move `opvn-script.sh` to a convenient location somewhere on root's PATH.

For security, make sure that permissions are set so that only root can modify (write) `opvn-script.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I see it. (Hard to tell remotely of course, and I don't have a linux box at hand.)

When you run a command via sudo, ie

```
$ sudo blah
```

there's a potential security hole -- consider, eg, if someone edited your script and added `vi /etc/passwd` to it. I *beleive* Linux changes the path to prevent this.

To check, write a script that just echoes `$PATH` and run it from sudo. If the path is not what you expect, you've found your problem.

Comment: Thanks Charlie!  Seems you and @John1024 came to the same conclusion because I got the same "not found" when I tried another script. Albeit yours mostly confirmed his in a different way :)

Answer (score 1):

Path to script was not in SUDO user profile, moved script to a SUDO path

Comment: Please mark this as accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Comment: Err, how does one do that in the Android app?  Nothing is obvious.....

Comment: Ah, just figured out out but I can accept my own answer till two days have passed.